# Is it always possible to converge from an integer to another integer?

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

Let's say I'm given a fixed integer, I. I'd like to know if it is always possible to find a function, that starting from any random integer J will converge to or oscillate reasonably close (let's say with 1% error) to I at +Inf.

If not possible, I'd also be interested to know if it could become possible by adding extra restrictions, for example I,J > 0 and I < J

Comment: What do you mean by "starting from $I$ will converge to ..." ? Are $I,J$ fixed or random?

Comment: @EclipseSun Sorry if the question wasn't clear, I've tried to improve it. Basically I have a given, fixed integer I and would like to know if it's possible to find a function that converges to it starting from any other random integer.

Comment: Read answer given by user2520938 and you will find out that your question is trivial.

Comment: Do you mean that if we put $a_0=J$, and $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$, then $\lim a_n=I$?.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a sequence $a_n$ that starts at $J$ and converges toward $I$ as $n\to\infty$, I think the one that is easiest defined is
$$
a_n=I-\frac{I-J}{n},\quad n\geq1
$$

Comment: Noteworthy, it works even if $I,J$ aren't integers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: A sequence of real numbers is a function $\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$. If you prefer continuous variable, it is easy to adapt Arthur's answer.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. It could be understood as looking for a sequence (hence indeed a function of $n$), or a function that is iterated ($a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$).

Answer (score 2):

Just take the sequence:

$$a_1=J,\ \ a_n=I\ \ \  \text{for }n>1$$

Answer (score 1):

The question is not too clear: what do you mean exactly by "function"? What do you mean "oscillating reasonably close at $+\infty$?

Anyways, here's a recipe to generate infinitely many analytic functions $f$ of real (non-negative) variable such that $f(0)=J$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=I$ ($I$ and $J$ being integers is irrelevant).

Just start with
$$
F(t)=J+t(I-J).
$$
This function is linear in $t$ and such that $F(0)=J$ and $F(1)=1$. Now take a substitution $t=\phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is **any** analytic function such that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\phi(x)=1$. Then $f(x)=F(\phi(x))$ will do.

E.g. you can choose
$$
\phi(x)=1-e^{-x},
$$
or
$$
\phi(x)=1-\frac1{x+1},
$$
or even
$$
\phi(x)=1-\frac1{x+1}\cos(x)
$$
if really want it to oscillate.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about a sequence with first term $I$ and that converges to $J$, take **ANY** converging sequence, from real $a_0$ to the real limit $a_\infty$, and map these to $J$ and $I$:

$$b_n:=(I-J)\frac{a_n-a_0}{a_\infty-a_0}+J.$$

---

If the question is about a function that, when iterated from $J$, yields $I$ in the limit, take

$$a_0=J,\ a_n:=f(a_{n-1})=I$$
or
$$a_0=J,\ a_n=f(a_{n-1}):=\frac{a_{n-1}+I}{2}.$$

It is also possible to find a function that will let the sequence oscillate forever while staying within $1\%$ of $I$ (provided reals are allowed or $I\ge100$).